# AddJsonBody() creates malformed Json

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I have a simple class that I'm trying to add to a POST call through RestSharp's `AddJsonBody()`

I keep getting the following exception though when running the Request `:\"The request body was not well-formed."\`

Here is the Json in question:

```
{"Id":null,"Profile":{"FirstName":"Fraiincis","LastName":"Doeor","Email":"De3leteMePls@gmail.com","Login":"De3leteMePls@gmail.com"},"Credentials":{"Password":{"Value":"myPassword"}}}
```

What's weird is that if I paste this into Postman it shows the last 3 curly braces are the issue.  However, if I just manually add formatting it's fine.  OR if I paste into a [Json Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) it tells me it's fine.

I can't figure out what's going on here and how to fix it.

---

Here is my code.  I followed this, https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage, very closely.

```
    public Task<IRestResponse<CustomerIdentity>> AddNewCustomerAsync(CustomerIdentity newCustomer)
    {
        Require.Argument("email", newCustomer.Profile.Email);

        var request = new RestRequest(resource: "{ApiVersion}/users?activate=true", method: Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter(name: "ApiVersion", value: Config.Version, type: ParameterType.UrlSegment);

        request.AddJsonBody(newCustomer);


        return ExecuteAsync<CustomerIdentity>(request);
    }

    public async Task<IRestResponse<T>> ExecuteAsync<T>(IRestRequest request) where T : class, new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient(baseUrl: Config.BaseUrl);

        request.AddHeader("authorization", "{ApiKey}");
        request.AddParameter(name: "ApiKey", value: Config.ApiKey, type: ParameterType.HttpHeader);

        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse<T>>();
        client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, restResponse =>
        {
            if (restResponse.ErrorException != null)
            {
                const string message = "Error retrieving response. Check inner details for more info";
                var oktaException = new ApplicationException(message, restResponse.ErrorException);
                throw oktaException;
            }
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(restResponse);
        });

        return await taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
```

I'm using RestSharp 105.2.3.0 BTW

Comment: Try to use `request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;` and `request.AddBody(yourObject);`. Of course without the `application/json=` part. If it works I will post it as an answer

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding.  I'm not coding, anywhere that I'm aware of, to add `application/json=` . No idea where it's coming from.  I've also tried your suggestion and it results in the same badly formatted Json.

Comment: Edit your question and add the RestSharp code you use to make the request it will be much easier